# LSTM Keras, predict prices

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to predict prices using a simple LSTM neural network the following way.

```
df = df.assign(future=df['adjclose'].shift(-1))
df.dropna(subset=['future'], how='all', inplace=True)
df = df.drop(columns=['date'])

X = pd.get_dummies(df.drop(['future'], axis=1))
Y = df['future']

X_Train, X_Test, Y_Train, Y_Test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.2, shuffle = shuffle)
    
model = deep_learning_model_creation(X_Train)
model.fit(
        X_Train,
        Y_Train, 
        epochs=epochs,
        batch_size=batch_size,
        validation_data=(X_Test, Y_Test)
)
predicted_stock_price = model.predict(X_Test)
X_Test['future'] = predicted_stock_price
print(X_Test)
```

The model creation:

```
def deep_learning_model_creation(X_Train, units=256):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(units=units,return_sequences=True,input_shape=(X_Train.shape[1], 1)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(LSTM(units=units,return_sequences=True))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(LSTM(units=units,return_sequences=True))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(LSTM(units=units))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Dense(units=1))
    model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='mean_squared_error')
    return model
```

My problem is that the result I get is  the same over all the rows it predicts as you can see in the print:

```
          open        high         low       close    adjclose    volume   upperband  middleband   lowerband     future
0   249.339996  253.000000  240.029999  244.070007  244.070007  70383300  285.259714  263.391998  241.524283  41.601418
10  217.089996  223.919998  200.000000  201.830002  201.830002  65620900  227.342036  213.808002  200.273968  41.601418
12  192.020004  199.449997  190.960007  199.020004  199.020004  64156600  226.865993  206.560001  186.254008  41.601418
15  189.669998  200.369995  184.899994  197.820007  197.820007  57032700  204.412283  192.804001  181.195718  41.601418
```

My goal is to produce a new dataframe with prices predicted for set amounts of time, for example get the adj close of the next following days so I can draw a chart of it.
Right now I'm kinda lost

Comment: Can you provide some sample data? In my experience, using LSTM and FF networks does not work, at best it predicts the previous day's value.

Comment: I extract the data directly from yahoo fin then add the indicators, but the data is mainly as you can see in the little sample I posted.